# Regarding the Spring data jpa named query not applying filter on child collection

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'm using spring data jpa In my application. I see filter is not being applied on the collections even though I have filter with respect to collection (child) in the named query in repository. When I enable show sql in the spring configuration file I see that for the first query to fetch the parent Entity the filter for the child collection is there but the subsequent queries to load child collections does not have the where clause to filter the child collections based on a condition. Any Ideas what could be the solution for this?

Comment: Please add the necessary parts of the repository (query method, query definition) to the question.